# Angular 8 - Validator with AngularFireDatabase call

Tags: angular, firebase

I have a problem while constructing a validator that calls firebase database. Code is below, let's take a look at the validator. Suppose I have array `['track1','track2']` in a database. When `trackName` field is filled with `track1` value, console returns `a`, as it should. But I figured out, that the `existingTrack` error didn't appear. Instead of this error, I've got below mentioned errors in FormGroup:

```
errors:
closed: false
destination: SafeSubscriber {closed: false, _parent: null, _parents: null, _subscriptions: null, syncErrorValue: null, …}
isStopped: false
syncErrorThrowable: true
syncErrorThrown: false
syncErrorValue: null
_parent: null
_parents: null
_subscriptions: [MapSubscriber]
__proto__: Object
```

I tried to change `validator` to `asyncValidator` in form builder, but after doing this, the validator stopped working at all. I think there might be something wrong with subscribe and pipe words, I'm not sure when to use which one.

Component code:

```
constructor(public fb: FormBuilder, private dataService: DataService) {}

ngOnInit() {

this.form = this.fb.group({
          newTrack: this.fb.control(false, Validators.required),

          trackName: this.fb.control(''),
          trackLength: this.fb.control('', [Validators.pattern('^[0-9]{1,}.[0-9]{1,2}$')]),
          trackSelect: this.fb.control(''),

          time: this.fb.control('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[0-9]{1,}:[0-9]{2}$')]),
          date: this.fb.control('', [Validators.required])
      }, 
      {validator: this.tracksDataValidator.bind(this)});
}

    tracksDataValidator(group: FormGroup) {

            const newTrack = group.get('newTrack').value;
            const trackSelect = group.get('trackSelect').value;
            const trackName = group.get('trackName').value;
            const trackLength = group.get('trackLength').value;


            return this.dataService.isTrackTaken(trackName).subscribe((res: any[]) => {
                    if (newTrack === true) {
                        if (res.length > 0) {
                            console.log('a');
                            return {existingTrack: true};
                        }
                        if (trackName === '' || trackLength === '') {
                            return {newTrackNotFilled: true};
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (trackSelect === '') {
                            return {noTrackSelected: true};
                        } else {
                            return null;
                        }
                    }
                });
        }
```

DataService

```
constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {}

isTrackTaken(trackName: string) {
        return this.db.list('/tracks').valueChanges()
            .pipe(map(tracks => tracks.filter((track: Track) => track.name === trackName)));
    }
```

EDIT:

I tried to create validator exactly in the same way as on alligator.io website, I changed form builder to

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
          newTrack: this.fb.control(false, Validators.required),

          trackName: this.fb.control('', [Validators.required], this.trackDataValidator.bind(this)),
          trackLength: this.fb.control('', [Validators.pattern('^[0-9]{1,}.[0-9]{1,2}$')]),
          trackSelect: this.fb.control(''),

          time: this.fb.control('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[0-9]{1,}:[0-9]{2}$')]),
          date: this.fb.control('', [Validators.required])
      });
```

and validator

```
trackDataValidator(control: FormControl) {
      return this.dataService.isTrackTaken(control.value).subscribe((res: any[]) => {
          return (res.length > 0) ? {existingTrack: true} : null;
      });
  }
```

DataService code was the same. After every typed letter in `trackName` field this error appeared:

```
ERROR Error: Expected validator to return Promise or Observable.
    at toObservable (forms.js:1466)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at FormControl.asyncValidator (forms.js:1446)
    at FormControl._runAsyncValidator (forms.js:4100)
    at FormControl.updateValueAndValidity (forms.js:4053)
    at FormControl.setValue (forms.js:4692)
    at updateControl (forms.js:3299)
    at DefaultValueAccessor.onChange (forms.js:3271)
    at DefaultValueAccessor._handleInput (forms.js:419)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (NewTrainingComponent.html:14)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following read :
https://alligator.io/angular/async-validators/

Basically you need to return an Observable and not the result of the subscription to the Observable.

Let me know if that works.

Also, the formcontrol is going to preform the subscribe itself aech time the form value changes so :

- be mindful of the API call and if necessary use the option : {updateOn: 'blur'} (FormControl('', {updateOn: 'blur'});)
- the Observable need to finish on subscription so use the pipes : first, last, take, or takeUntil.

Comment: I just tried to do in the same way, the results are at the end of my question